# Connecting an analog level sensor

Tags: sensor, analog-to-digital, voltage

First time poster here. I'm okay with the programming side but have some issue with the electronics side

I have raspberry pi 4 and wish to connect a submersible water level sensor to it. The sensor has a power input of 5VDC and has an analog output of 0.5-4.5V. To read the data I was thinking about connecting the Pi to an ADS1115.

My question is can I power the sensor through the ADS115 as well?

Are they any better solutions

Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided the ADS115 requires the same voltage supply as the sensor.

If so just add add a wire between the ADS115 and sensor power pins.

Similarly you need to connect the Pi ground to the ADS115 ground.  Add a wire between the ADS115 and sensor ground pins.